# comma and space separated number and hyphen separated string regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to validate the following string using jquery i need regex please help find solution for this,

The valid strings are,

```
(1)1,2,3,4,1,2-8
(2)1,2, 3, 4, 1, 2-8
```

Should also accept commas and commas with spaces and also the number should be hyphen separated

I have tried the following regex ,

```
^([0-9]+(-[0-9]+)?)(,([0-9]+(-[0-9]+)?))*$
```

Comment: ^([0-9]+(-[0-9]+)?)(\s*,\s*([0-9]+(-[0-9]+)?))*$ this regex worked for me

Comment: What IS that thing?  (what does the string represent?)

Comment: Two examples of valid strings is not even _nearly_ enough to reverse engineer a correct regular expression. Provide ten valid strings and ten invalid ones or, better, _describe the semantics_ of your input.

Comment: The number string is a comma separated string which will have commas with space or without space and the number can be single or they can be hyphen separated but the main delimiter will be a comma.does this explain you my requirement

Answer (score 0):

This one works for the strings you posted:

```
var rx = new RegExp(/^\(\d\)(\d,\s*){5}\d\-\d$/);
```

However, it wasn't clear to me whether the `(1)` and `(2)` were supposed to be part of the strings. If not, use this:

```
var r2 = new RegExp(/^(\d,\s*){5}\d\-\d$/);
// a digit, followed by a comma, followed by some whitespace, repeated five times
// with a digit-hyphen-digit sequence at the end
```